# Imagefont truetype cannot open resource

Tags: python, django, truetype

Cannot open . ttf file from media folder
But it's work Localserver
But now the project hosting to pythonanywhere

```
class SmartRCBack(models.Model):
    reg_number = models.CharField(max_length=10,primary_key=True)
    month_year = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    wheelbase = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    cubic = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    cylinder = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    ledan_unledan = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    maker = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    body_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    seating = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    rto = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    finance = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)

    now = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True,auto_created=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='SmartRc/',blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-now',)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        img = Image.open('media/back.png' )
        # fnt = ImageFont.truetype('/Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf', 15)
        d = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
        bold = ImageFont.truetype("media/arial-BoldMT.ttf",size=15,)
        font = ImageFont.truetype("media/Arial-BoldMT.ttf",size=16,)
        d.text((226,48), self.type, fill=(14, 15, 15),font=bold, stroke_fill="black")
        d.text((40,93), self.reg_number, fill=(14, 15, 15),font=font, stroke_fill="black")
        d.text((40,134), self.month_year, fill=(14, 15, 15),font=font, stroke_fill="black")
        d.text((40,174), self.wheelbase, fill=(14, 15, 15),font=font, stroke_fill="black")
        d.text((40,213), self.cubic, fill=(14, 15, 15),font=font, stroke_fill="black")
        d.text((40,253), self.cylinder, fill=(14, 15, 15),font=font, stroke_fill="black")
        d.text((40,315), self.ledan_unledan, fill=(14, 15, 15),font=font, stroke_fill="black")
        d.text((196,93), self.maker, fill=(14, 15, 15),font=font, stroke_fill="black")
        d.text((196,134), self.model, fill=(14, 15, 15),font=font, stroke_fill="black")
        d.text((196,174), self.color, fill=(14, 15, 15),font=font, stroke_fill="black")
        d.text((196,213), self.body_type, fill=(14, 15, 15),font=font, stroke_fill="black")
        d.text((196,253), self.seating, fill=(14, 15, 15),font=font, stroke_fill="black")
        d.text((196,298), "LIFE TIME", fill=(14, 15, 15),font=font, stroke_fill="black")
        d.text((451,399), self.rto, fill=(14, 15, 15),font=font, stroke_fill="black")
        if self.finance:
            textwrapped = textwrap.wrap(self.finance, width=20)
            d.text((455,259), '\n'.join(textwrapped), fill=(14, 15, 15),font=font, stroke_fill="black")
        img.save(f'{self.reg_number} back.png')
        destination_file = open(f'{self.reg_number} back.png', 'rb')
        self.image.save(f'{self.reg_number} back.png', File(destination_file), save=False)

        super(SmartRCBack, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.rto} {self.reg_number}'
```

I got a error this line so i try 3 ways to solve the problem
This 3 ways

```
font = ImageFont.truetype("arial-BoldMT.ttf", size =16)
```

```
font = ImageFont.truetype("fullpath of the file/arial-BoldMT.ttf", size =16)
```

```
font = ImageFont.truetype("settings.MEDIA_ROOT/arial-BoldMT.ttf", size =16)
```

```
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = "/home/Amar2022/rto/media"
STATIC_ROOT = "/home/Amar2022/rto/static"
```

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('rc/',include('rc.urls'))
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

[pythonanywhere web config path image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpCCt.png)

Error

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: https://shinewithanvika2022.pythonanywhere.com/admin/banner/smartrcback/add/

Django Version: 4.0.4
Python Version: 3.9.5
Installed Applications:
['jazzmin',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'rest_framework.authtoken',
 'rest_framework_simplejwt',
 'mocktest',
 'student',
 'widget_tweaks',
 'banner']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shinewithanvika2022/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/shinewithanvika2022/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/shinewithanvika2022/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 683, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shinewithanvika2022/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 133, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shinewithanvika2022/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 62, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shinewithanvika2022/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 242, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shinewithanvika2022/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1885, in add_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/home/shinewithanvika2022/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shinewithanvika2022/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 133, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shinewithanvika2022/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1745, in changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/home/shinewithanvika2022/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1797, in _changeform_view
    self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)
  File "/home/shinewithanvika2022/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1220, in save_model
    obj.save()
  File "/home/shinewithanvika2022/examproject/banner/models.py", line 129, in save
    bold = ImageFont.truetype("arial-BoldMT.ttf",size=15,)
  File "/home/shinewithanvika2022/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 878, in truetype
    return freetype(font)
  File "/home/shinewithanvika2022/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 875, in freetype
    return FreeTypeFont(font, size, index, encoding, layout_engine)
  File "/home/shinewithanvika2022/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 226, in __init__
    self.font = core.getfont(

Exception Type: OSError at /admin/banner/smartrcback/add/
Exception Value: cannot open resource
```

But it's work ImageFont.load_default()
I want 3 different fonts arialbold, arialbt, arialblack, arial
So it's work local machine
If any package available to install the fonts

Thanks to read the question

Comment: Please post the error message with full traceback

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually serve the files: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DjangoStaticFiles/

Comment: try but got same error...!